# How to hide intermediate values of solid gauge chart of highcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I wanted to remove intermediate number that are appeared on solid gauge chart.
e.g. I want to hide 100 from chart given in link.

[Solid gauge chart](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/gauge-solid/)

Here is my code of chart.

```
function myfun(data) {
var gaugeOptions = {
chart: {
  renderTo: 'mydiv',
  type: 'solidgauge'
},
title: null,
pane: {
  center: ['50%', '85%'],
  size: '140%',
  startAngle: -90,
  endAngle: 90,
  background: {
    backgroundColor: (window.Highcharts.theme && window.Highcharts.theme.background2) || '#EEE',
    innerRadius: '60%',
    outerRadius: '100%',
    shape: 'arc'
  }
},
tooltip: {
  enabled: false
},
// the value axis
yAxis: {
  stops: [
    [0.0, '#DF5353'], // red
    [0.5, '#DF5353'],
    [0.51, '#DDDF0D'],
    [0.79, '#DDDF0D'], // yellow
    [0.8, '#55BF3B'],
    [1, '#55BF3B'] // green
  ],
  lineWidth: 0,
  minTickInterval: 100,
  minorTickInterval: null,
  tickPixelInterval: 400,
  tickWidth: 0,
  title: {
    y: -110
  },
  labels: {
    y: 16
  }
},
plotOptions: {
  solidgauge: {
    dataLabels: {
      y: 5,
      borderWidth: 0,
      useHTML: true
    }
  }
}
};
// The speed gauge
$('#mydiv')
.highcharts(
  window.Highcharts
  .merge(
    gaugeOptions, {
      yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        title: {
          text: ''
        }
      },
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'Speed',
        data: [totalHealthScore],
        dataLabels: {
          format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:25px;color:' + ((window.Highcharts
              .theme && window.Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black') +
            '">{y}</span><br/>' + '<span style="font-size:12px;color:silver">Score</span></div>'
        },
        tooltip: {
          valueSuffix: ' Score'
        }
      }]
    }));
}
```

How do I hide values 2.5 and 100 from charts given in the link??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can affect the position of the ticks using tickInterval and startOnTick, e.g.

```
yAxis: {
        tickInterval:200,
        startOnTick:true,
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DdAr6/

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickInterval

Comment: For anyone else coming here in need for start + end point only, set tickPixelInterval to null and tickInterval to the same as your max value. http://jsfiddle.net/f8NSe/3/

Answer (score 3):

The number of steps need to be defined for the y axis.

In the speedometer's code:

```
yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 200,
    labels: {step:2},
    title: {
        text: 'Speed'
    }       
}
```

In the tachometer's code:

```
yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 5,
    labels: {step:2},
    title: {
        text: 'RPM'
    }       
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/y62sj/ for the full code.

Comment: This solution also relies on tickPixelInterval being set.

Comment: That's true. As long as the original code he posted isn't altered beyond one of our two solutions, OP won't have to worry about setting it, though. An example of this code with the steps defined next to the tickPixelInterval member (with the added bonus of only having to be set once for all graphs) can be seen at http://jsfiddle.net/W6mRh/1/